# No se muestran los datos en Crystal Reports Dinamico

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset

Buen día,

Espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, estoy ocupando Crystal 13.0.32 y VB.NET 2019. Tengo un reporte principal donde solo hay campos de formula y un subinforme, las formulas las lleno mediante un SP y el subreporte mediante un DataSet dinamico. Ambos datos me los muestra pero si quito el código del otro, y yo quiero que me muestre los datos de las formulas y la tabla, aquí esta mi código para que se entienda mejor:

```
'Variable global del Form
Dim objRpt As New ReporteGastos

...

Sub X()

For i = 0 To listaConfirmaIDs.Count - 1 'Es una lista que devuelve puros IDs de la base, cada ID genera un reporte

Dim datosFormulas= ejecutarQueryDataReader("ObtenerDatosReporteSolicitudGasto '" & dataBase & "', " & listaConfirmaIDs(i).ToString & "", "Conexion") 'obtengo los datos de las formulas con un SP

Dim datosPorcentajesDS = llenaDataSet(QuerySQL("SELECT Socio FROM  SOCIOS WHERE Banco = 1 AND Estacion = " & datosSolicitudGastos(7).ToString & ""), dataBase).Tables("tabla1") 'Función que devuelve DataSet


'Aquí lleno las formulas del reporte principal

ReporteForm.ReporteGastos1.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("CantidadNumero").Text = "'" & datosFormulas(3).ToString & "'"
                                                            ReporteForm.ReporteGastos1.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("Concepto").Text = "'" & datosFormulas(4).ToString & "'"
                                                            ReporteForm.ReporteGastos1.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("Referencia").Text = "'" & datosFormulas(5).ToString & "'"

'Aquí asigno el datasource del subreporte, pero si dejo estas tres líneas no me muestra los datos de las formulas, y si lo quito si me lo muestra, el problema yo creo debe ser el ReportSource que se vuelve a asignar pero no encuentro como solucionarlo
 
objRpt.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(datosPorcentajesDS)
ReporteForm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
ReporteForm.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

ReporteForm.ShowDialog()

Next

End Sub

'Función para llenar el DataSet dinamico
Public Function QuerySQL(Query As String) As String
        Dim sql As String = Nothing
        Dim inSql As String = Nothing
        Dim firstPart As String = Nothing
        Dim lastPart As String = Nothing
        Dim selectStart As Integer = 0
        Dim fromStart As Integer = 0
        Dim fields As String() = Nothing
        Dim sep As String() = {","}
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim MyText As TextObject
        inSql = Query
        inSql = inSql.ToUpper()
        selectStart = inSql.IndexOf("SELECT")
        fromStart = inSql.IndexOf("FROM")
        selectStart = selectStart + 6
        firstPart = inSql.Substring(selectStart, (fromStart - selectStart))
        lastPart = inSql.Substring(fromStart, inSql.Length - fromStart)
        fields = firstPart.Split(","c)
        firstPart = ""

        For i = 0 To fields.Length - 1

            If i > 0 Then
                firstPart = firstPart & ", " & fields(i).ToString() & " AS DATACOLUMN" & (i + 1)
                firstPart.Trim()
                MyText = CType(objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects((i + 1).ToString), TextObject)
                'MyText = CType(objRpt.Subreports(0).ReportDefinition.ReportObjects((i + 1).ToString), TextObject)
                MyText.Text = fields(i).ToString()
            Else
                firstPart = firstPart & fields(i).ToString() & " AS DATACOLUMN" & (i + 1)
                firstPart.Trim()
                MyText = CType(objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects(i + 1), TextObject)
                'MyText = CType(objRpt.Subreports(0).ReportDefinition.ReportObjects((i + 1).ToString), TextObject)
                MyText.Text = fields(i).ToString()
            End If
        Next

        sql = "SELECT " & firstPart & " " & lastPart
        Return sql
    End Function
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Intentaste asignar el dataset como origen de datos directamente en el reporte? Llenas el dataset por código y luego solo deberías instanciar (as new) el reporte para llamarlo y refrescarlo.

Comment: Si asigne un dataset para el reporte principal y otro para el subreporte pero sigue pasando lo mismo, en el momento que coloco esta linea ReporteForm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt solo da prioridad al subreporte.

Comment: Se que va a parecer una locura, pero en lugar de asignar el reporte al `ReporteForm` (esas 3 líneas de las que hablas) hacé esto `objRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 1, 100)` sacalo con la impresora PDF y contame si el resultado es el mismo por favor.